# How to fix ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) - RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm beginner and in the mailer code Ruby on Rails I have an error "ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)" between my code and his test.

**Error:**

```
UtilisateurMailerTest#test_account_activation:

ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
    app/mailers/utilisateur_mailer.rb:8:in `account_activation'
    test/mailers/utilisateur_mailer_test.rb:6
```

**utilisateur_mailer_test.rb:**

```
class UtilisateurMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  test "account_activation" do
           mail = UtilisateurMailer.account_activation
(line6)    assert_equal "Account activation", mail.subject
           assert_equal ["to@example.org"], mail.to
           assert_equal ["from@example.com"], mail.from
           assert_match "Hi", mail.body.encoded
  end
```

**utilisateur_mailer.rb:**
........

```
Line8:
  def account_activation(utilisateur)
    @utilisateur = utilisateur
    mail to: utilisateur.email, subject: "Activation du compte"
  end
```

I've tryed to delete ", mail.subject" and the subject: "Activation du compte" and it returns: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3)

I'm a novice.. thanks for your answers!

Comment: The problem is there. You must pass an `utilisateur` as an argument when invoking `account_activation`.

Comment: Thanx Sebastian for your reply, but I don't understand why it doesn't use my instance variable "@utilisateur = utilisateur" where the email address was submit inside utilisateur_mail.rb file..

Comment: What do you mean? That's not how it works. If you declare a method with n amounts of mandatory arguments, you should invoke that method with the same amount of parameters. There's no explicit incorporation of variables (instance/local/global) within a method call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this issue while upgrading from Rails v5.2.3 to v5.2.4 and fixed it by upgrading the following gem

```
gem 'awesome_nested_set', '~> 3.2.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

has you can see the error message is telling you that one of your method is waiting for an argument but nothing was passed to it.

In your `utilisateur_mailer_test.rb`, you can see that you are calling the method `account_activation` that you created in the `utilisateur_mailer.rb`.

As you can see this method needs an *utilisateur* parameter to be executed but when you are calling this method inside of your `utilisateur_mailer_test.rb`, you are not passing anything to it :
`mail = UtilisateurMailer.account_activation`

You must specify an *utilisateur* argument here by creating a user through a factory using [FactoryBot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot) with [Faker](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker) for example.

Good luck ! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Olivier for your details answer ! 

But I missed something because inside  utilisateur_mailer.rb I add a parameter (utilisateur) and use an instante variable "@utilisateur = utilisateur" where the email address has been informed during the registration. 

I create a "create_utilisateurs.rb" file inside (db > migrate) to save (names/emails) on the DB. 
My DB have many users, what email adress can I put in "utilisateur_mailer.rb" to correct this error.

It is possible the problem came from because I'm in localhost in this case ?

Tx again ;)